# Mysql 5.6 UTF-8 (utf8mb4) still displaying incorrect characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mysql-5.6

I did a conversion of my database to utf8mb4, yet it still returns incorrect UTF8 characters:

For example, `Café` becomes `CafÃ©`

Here are my mysql collation variables:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'; SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

Also, my DB has slowed down at least 10x since switching to utf8.

Answer (score 1):

Mojibake.  This is the classic case of

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8mb4 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8mb4`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, but it should have been that.

If you need to **fix for the data** it takes a "2-step ALTER", something like

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (`NOT NULL`, etc) was already on the column.